# Syntax error in INSERT INTO Statement while trying to input values in the Database

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, ms-access

Hi i basically am creating a registration page. I am getting an error saying "Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement." Also sometimes am getting an Error saying that the connection is open or something. It was working before in a different table and different fields etc...The code is as follows

```
public partial class Registration : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    static OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=D:\New folder\Project 1.0\WebSite1\New Microsoft Office Access 2007 Database.accdb");
    OleDbDataAdapter ada = new OleDbDataAdapter();
    OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
    OleDbDataReader dr;
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}

protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string str = "insert into User_Registeration (First_Name, Last_name, Phone_No, Username, Password, Email, Address, City, Country, Zipcode)" +
         "values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
    con.Open();
    cmd = new OleDbCommand(str, con);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p1", TextBox1.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p2", TextBox2.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p3", TextBox3.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p4", TextBox4.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p5", TextBox5.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p6", TextBox6.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p7", TextBox8.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p8", TextBox12.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p9", TextBox9.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p10", TextBox11.Text);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();
}
```

}

And my mc access table has the following structure...

ID  First_Name  Last_name   Phone_No    Username    Password    Email   Address City    Country Zipcode

Can someone please help me? :)
Thank you :)

Comment: Please show the actual error messages.

Comment: 1.The connection was not closed. The connection's current state is open.

Comment: 2.Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use this query:

```
  string str = "insert into User_Registeration (First_Name, Last_name, Phone_No, [Username], [Password], [Email], [Address], City, Country, Zipcode)" +
     " values (@p1, @p2, @p3,@p4, @p5,@p6, @p7,@p8,@p9,@p10)";
```

Comment: check if cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() >0 then your data is inserted.

Comment: Still an error this time its different - "Number of query values and destination fields are not the same."

Comment: @ Zeeshand Anjum Hi :) How do i check that? Could you please tell me? Am really new to all this >.<

Comment: user2107703 has put @p8 twice in the string

Comment: Yea there was @p8 twice! Thanks it worked! Thank you :) But the other error that i get sometimes "The connection was not closed. The connection's current state is open." Is there something that i can do about that? It doesn't come every time it comes nonetheless..

Comment: use try catch finally block. in finally block check 
if (myConnection != null && myConnection.State != ConnectionState.Closed)
{myConnection.close(); } 

this will always close connection if it is not closed

Comment: to check no of rows inserted:
int c = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
if(c>0){ // successfully inserted c rows where c is the number of rows
}else{
//unable to insert data
}

Comment: Ok will do that :) Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is caused by the word PASSWORD. This word is a [reserved word in JET](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/321266) (MS-Access)
To use that word in your sql commands you need to encapsulate it with square brackets.

Of course when you add parameters to your query you should be sure to add the exact number of parameters expected by the placeholders in your query.
You have 10 placeholders (?) so you need 10 parameters and in the exact order expected by the respective fields

So, summarizing

```
string str = "insert into User_Registeration (First_Name, Last_name, Phone_No, " + 
             "Username, [Password], Email, Address, City, Country, Zipcode)" +
             "values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
```

Comment: Yup got it! Thanks a lot! Btw thanks for helping earlier too with that question i had asked :)

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a space in this line :

```
string str = "insert into User_Registeration (First_Name, Last_name, Phone_No, Username, Password, Email, Address, City, Country, Zipcode)" +
     "values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
```

should be :

```
string str = "insert into User_Registeration (First_Name, Last_name, Phone_No, Username, Password, Email, Address, City, Country, Zipcode)" +
     " values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
```

Comment: Still getting the same error "Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement." pointing at cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();